# New to Rails Caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, caching

Okay, I'm working with a new rails application that needs to handle MAX around 1 million records at any one time.

**At any one time there's going to be a maximum of:**

- 1500 Outlets
- 400 Users
- 1 million Monitoring Records

I have this running on a Linode 512 VPS:

- 512MB RAM
- 20GB Storage

I'm new to caching on Rails, and I have no idea where to start.

The dashboard, runs the following query:

```
# Controller
@outlets = Outlet.includes(:current_monitorings).where(:is_active => 'true')

# Model
has_many :current_monitorings, :class_name => "Monitoring", :conditions => proc { [ 'monitorings.created_at > ?', Time.now.midnight ] }
```

How would I cache this effectively?

Also, I a standard CRUD Setup in my Monitorings_controller. How might I work with caching that?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I mentioned on your earlier question, it is quite likely you don't need any caching for this. None of your numbers are big by modern standards. With index on monitorings(outlet_id,created_at) this outer jojn query between outlets and monitorings should be served by postgres very fast.  Have you tried it and timed it? I expect you should be able to execute that query hundreds of times per second. Only cache things which can't be calculated to your service requirements because caching introduces new issues (consistency, stale data and expiry policy, memory management, additional service).

Comment: It's not just the query, for some reason it's slowing everything down.. a lot. I filled the app with dummy data for around 600,000 Monitorings, and the query now takes 17 seconds to complete

Comment: It's changed from the original post, I will have around 2000 outlets, with 1,000,000 monitorings associated with them.
I want to display a dashboard, with each of these turning green when a monitoring is associated with them today. The current query takes well into 5 minutes, and uses 100% of CPU.

Comment: The query shouldn't be so slow, can you capture the generated sql from your logs, then do an `explain analyze` with it in psql?  Also post your table and index definitions. Scanning 2000 outlets and joining on an index lookup should happen in milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: I'm away from my development machine at the moment, I need to change the query slightly, would it be possible to run the query on only the LAST monitoring record associated with an outlet, and check if it was created today? At the moment when I try and run the query it crashes, because 1million records were created today according to my dummy data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this links for more details on Caching in rails

http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=18

http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html